# Finding mismatches in zero positions from elements of the same list

Tags: r, list, function, vector, error-handling

I wonder how to create a `if()` condition to capture when `0` values in one element of a `list()` are not `0` for the corresponding positions in the second element of the same `list()`?

For example, in `A` list, the first two values of `x` are `0`, but the first two values of `y` are NOT `0`. So, I want to catch this as an `error` (`stop`).

However, in `B` list, the first three values of `x` are `0`, and the first three values of `y` are `0` as well. So, I want to catch this as a (`warning`).

In ALL other types of `list` (e.g., list `C` below), I want no `warning` or `stop`.

```
( A = list(x = c(0,0,2,2), y = c(3,3,1,1)) ) # `stop()`

( B = list(x = c(0,0,0,1,1,1), y = c(0,0,0,1,1,1)) ) # `warning()`

( C = list(x = c(5,5,5), y=c(1,1,1)) ) # no `stop` or `warning`.
```

Comment: Why not sum the 2 vector and check if the same element of A and the sum are equal to 0 ? (are negative values possible ? Is there a case where there neither an error or a warning ?

Comment: I think so. Other question, are the vector always the same size ? Why not use a data.frame structure, that could help you use rowSums or something like that

Comment: I did one, but I'm not sure it fit your issue...I don't understand for which case there is no warning/error, could you provide an exemple of such case ? PS : Edit your code with comments to highlight that A trigger error and B trigger warning, I think it's more readible

Comment: Answer works on all cases unless we missed one or values can be negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a try to resolve your issue.

It depend on the values being between 0 and Inf, and the vector having the same length. I think it works on more than 2 vector if you want.

```
( A = list(x = c(0,0,2,2), y = c(3,3,1,1)) ) # Expect error
( B = list(x = c(0,0,0,1,1,1), y = c(0,0,0,1,1,1)) ) # Expect warning
( C = list(x = c(5,5,5), y=c(1,1,1)) ) # Expect fine

check <- function(l){
  df <- as.data.frame(l)
  if(any(df == 0)){
    if(any(rowSums(df) == df[,1]) ){
      warning("this is a warning")
    } else {
      stop("this is an error")
    }
  }
}

check(A)
check(B)
check(C)
```

Comment: You mean NA values ?

Comment: Okay, I was tinkering but it need to think with a different way, and could have been solved by using different nested if conditions... I hope it will works fine ;)

Comment: I have asked a follow-up [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66912637/7223434) in case interested.