# Follow-up: Finding mismatches in zero positions from elements of the same list

Tags: r, list, function, vector, error-handling

I'm following up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66843307/7223434). I want to create an `if()` condition to capture when 0 values in one element of a `list()` are not 0 for the corresponding positions in the second element of the same `list()`?

For example, in `A` list, the first two values of `x` are `0`, but the first two values of `y` are NOT `0`. So, I want to catch this as an `error` (`stop`).

However, in `B` list, the first three values of `x` are `0`, and the first three values of `y` are `0` as well. So, I want to catch this as a (`warning`).

**Q:** Although I expect error for `D` list, I wonder why my `if()` doesn't catch it, is there a fix?

```
( A = list(x = c(0,0,2,2), y = c(3,3,1,1)) ) # Expect error
( B = list(x = c(0,0,0,1,1,1), y = c(0,0,0,1,1,1)) ) # Expect warning
( C = list(x = c(5,5,5), y=c(1,1,1)) ) # Expect fine


( D = list(x = c(0,1,1,0), y = c(2,1,0,0)) ) ## Expect error but my function doesn't catch it!



check <- function(l){
  df <- as.data.frame(l)
  if(any(df == 0)){
    if(any(rowSums(df) == df[,1]) ){
      warning("this is a warning")
    } else {
      stop("this is an error")
    }
  }
}

check(A) # Works fine
check(B) # Works fine
check(C) # Works fine

check(D) # NOT OK! Doesn't throw any error!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `xor`

```
check <- function(l){
  
  if(any(unlist(l) == 0)){
    if(!any(do.call(xor, l)) ){
      warning("this is a warning")
    } else {
      stop("this is an error")
    }
  }
}
```

-testing

```
check(A)
#Error in check(A) : this is an error

check(B)
#Warning message:
#In check(B) : this is a warning
check(C)
check(D)
#Error in check(D) : this is an error
```

---

Or change the `rowSums` to

```
check <- function(l){
  df <- as.data.frame(l)
  if(any(df == 0)){
    if(!any(rowSums(df == 0) == 1) ){
      warning("this is a warning")
    } else {
      stop("this is an error")
    }
  }
  }
  
check(A)
#Error in check(A) : this is an error
check(B)
#Warning message:
#In check(B) : this is a warning
check(C)
check(D)
#Error in check(D) : this is an error
```

Comment: xor return true only when one of the element is true and not both. any check if there areany such cases and negate

Comment: @rnorouzian unlike your original function which converts to `data.frame`, I am calling the function xor on the `list` itself.  to compare each corresponding element of list have an `exclusive` zero or not.  You may have used `do.call(rbind` or `do.call(c` when applying a list of data.sets

Comment: @rnorouzian `rbind` takes two input datasets at a time `rbind(df1, df2)` and if there are 3 datasets, we may have to do `rbind(rbind(df1, df2), df3)`.  In a `list`, this will be iteratively called from the first list elemnt to the last by one `rbind` call with `do.call`

Comment: @rnorouzian still with `do.call(xor, d1)`.  You may know that `data.frame` is a `list` with columns having equal length (or list elements with equal length)

Comment: @rnorouzian how many columns are there in your actual data.  I assume this is 2 columns or 2 element list

Comment: @rnorouzian For more than 2 columns, you can use `rowSums(d1 == 0) == 1` for presence of only one 0

Comment: @rnorouzian i updated with `rowSums` so you may not have to worry about

Comment: @rnorouzian yes, you can do

Comment: @rnorouzian what is the issue there?

Comment: I meant `rowSums(df` and not `l`

Comment: You are using `rowSums` on a `list` which wouldn't work.  Can you check my second solution where I used `df <- as.data.frame(l)`

Comment: @rnorouzian ok will check

Comment: @rnorouzian it doesn't have any 0 in it.  What is the expected

Comment: @rnorouzian if it is a differnt condition, can you post as a new question

Comment: @rnorouzian in that one, it returns an error.  But here, the condition is to check for 0 values

Comment: @rnorouzian do you want to check if any element is not the same in that position

Comment: @rnorouzian I am not following you.  Can you post as a new question.  In that way, it becomes more clear

Comment: No problem, sure. Thank you very much.